# Google Analytics "Sessions that Enter at Transaction"

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I have set up Google Analytics E-Commerce.
When I look in "Shopping Behaviour" > "Sessions with Transactions" it is split in two so there are two blocks and one of them are called "Sessions that Enter at Transaction".
This means that "Transactions" are higher than "Check-out" in the funnel which makes no sense.

Has anyone experienced the same?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related.

Comment: @DaImTo Is stackoverflow only for programming?

Comment: Yes stack overflow is a programing site https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  If your having an issue with a web application you might try https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This can mean that you have **duplicate transactions**. Probably the user can later access the page where the website sends the transaction information to Analytics (for example because the user has saved it in a bookmark) and the system records it as a new transaction.

Comment: I assume there is no way around this?

Comment: There are solutions for the future. For example, you can prevent that page from being reached a second time or you can avoid sending the code after it has already been sent once.